# Python C++ extension with SWIG - calling a function by importing module

Tags: c++, python, function, swig, init

how can I write an C++ lib and make it to an python extension with SWIG and by importing the module `import module` it will automaticaly call an function that initializes some global variables.

I have tried to rename the function to `__init__()`, but when I import the module it isnt called.

what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code in an init section in the SWIG interface file:

```
%init %{
    my_init_function();
%}
```

This code will be added to the generated swig wrapper and be called when module is imported.

[SWIG 2.0](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html) Section 5.6.2: [Code Insertion Blocks](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn42)